# What is the PNG files in Lottie? Are they vectorized?

Tags: android, zeplin

I got Lottie files from the designer and it contains `png` files.

The size are small. However, it seems low quality. And I added it into the view and built and launched my app and It looks blurry.

What I guess is, The parts Lottie can't vectorize remains as `PNG` files. And the others are in `json`.

Is that right?

If yes, The second question is, `Lottie` has some functionality to use `PNG` files like vectorized image source with its connected `json` file?

I need to correspond the device screens(resolutions). Does `json+PNG` can correspond all the resolutions or not? If it is not, Should I separate them and for the PNG part, I need `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xdpi`, ... ones like in Zeplin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lottie Library supports PNG files but I think your designer made a mistake, it's better to use Vectors `ONLY` Lottie cannot convert PNG images into the vectors, so you have to include them into your project

> Lottie has some functionality to use PNG files like vectorized image source with its connected JSON file?

NO

Lottie doesn't make the PNG vectorized. However, your animation will run normally just like it's demo, there is no problem with functionality. Since it is not vectorized, the image can look blurry or broken.

> I need to correspond the device screens(resolutions). Does json+PNG can correspond all the resolutions or not? If it is not, Should I separate them and for the PNG part, I need mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, ... ones like in Zeplin?

NO

I think you will be in trouble with multiple screen resolutions, after all, the PNG is just a PNG

Comment: Thanks, but. If then. The first question is NO. vectorized means it  can correspond all the resolutions. Otherwise, PNG image will look blurry or crashed.